# How to prevent mouseover effect in GTK button

Tags: c++, c, gtk

I have a doubt about mouseover effect when I create a button and put an image with
`gtk_button_set_image`. If I remove the relief with `gtk_button_set_relief`, I can't see the border, but when I put the mouse over the button, border appears.

Is there any solution so that this doesn't occur?

Answer (score 0):

I guess it's just your GTK+ theme's choice.

Comment: I.e. change the theme, not the button.