# GtkButton vs. GtkLabel font relief: how to customise one or the other?

Tags: button, label, pygtk, subclass, styles

### Context

I'm working on an application with PyGtk that would more or less work as a panel, much like gnome-panel. Ideally, on the panel i am making, i want a button without border (NB: i am in the process of learning GUI coding with PyGtk).

### Problem

I have understood [from another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5439134/how-to-prevent-mouseover-effect-in-gtk-button) as well as [documentation](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/3.0/GtkButton.html#gtk-button-set-relief) that the `gtk_button_set_relief(GtkButton, GTK_RELIEF_NONE)` cancels the button relief on `GTK_STATE_NORMAL` only. Hence when hovering the button, relief appears again (side note: this is frankly annoying that such options are partially worked out really).

An alternative to the problem is to use a GtkLabel and make a GtkEventBox its parent and make it function as a button. There is an issue however: while a GtkButton font has a relief, the GtkLabel's has none. See screenshot here below:

[image: From left to right: GtkLabel without font relief and GtkButton with font relief]

*From left to right: GtkLabel without font relief and GtkButton with font relief*

### Questions

Now perhaps you can help me to solve the above with your suggestions. What i am thinking of is:

1. What is causing the relief of the font on these GtkWidgets: the theme or the Gtk base itself?
2. How can i add relief to the font of the label? OR
3. How can i remove the border relief of the button in all states?
4. More generally, how can can i create my own widget (subclassing either GtkLabel or GtkButton) using PyGtk? (I have seen [an example on this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4212385/making-a-gtkbutton-round), but that's C i believe)
5. Is there any alternative i haven't thought of?
6. Should i use another GUI library altogether?

Thanks.
Benjamin :)

---

**Edit:** the former resize-grip handle issue with GtkEventBox appears to be the effect of [a Gtk+ bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gtk+2.0/+bug/704105).